# DateFormatting resulting in null

Tags: ios, objective-c, date, formatting

I have a date string from server "5/31/2017 10:05:59 AM +00:00", I am trying to convert it into NSDate,

```
    NSString *expiration = [responseObject valueForKey:@".expires"];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a +zz";
    dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
    NSDate *expiryDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:expiration];
    EKLog(@"expiry date %@", expiryDate);
```

But it gives me null, Plase Help Thanks.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/romaonthego/5138532 this will help you for the date formatter in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set dateformat as

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a z";
```

full code is

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a z";
dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
NSDate *expiryDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"5/31/2017 10:05:59 AM +00:00"];
NSLog(@"expiry date %@", expiryDate);
```

**output**

[image]

Comment: Don't post images of text! Heck, is it really easier for you to post an image instead of simple copy/paste?? Or does your computer OS not support copy&paste of simple text? In that case: get a more recent OS (one newer than the 70ies.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a z";
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using a wrong date format. `5/31/2017 10:05:59 AM +00:00`

Instead of `MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a +zz`, you should be using '`M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a Z`

But before using the `NSDateFomatter`, you should remove the `:` from the time zone using `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString`, as `Z` will parse date to `+0000`

For more testing, you can use this link : http://nsdateformatter.com

Answer (score 0):

Your Code is correct but the date format is wrong.
Check the below code

> Z instead of zz

```
NSString *expiration =@"5/31/2017 10:05:59 AM +00:00";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a Z";
dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
NSDate *expiryDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:expiration];
NSLog(@"expiry date %@", expiryDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, just try like this: `heredateFormatter.dateFormat = @"MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss a zz";`